# Limit involving a trigonometric function

Tags: calculus

How do I solve this problem? Will I have to find the derivative and use L'Hopitals rule?

I tried something but don't know where to go from there

$$\lim_{t\to2} \frac{\sin(t-2)}{t^2-4} = \lim_{t\to2} \frac{\sin(t)\cos(2)-\sin(2)\cos(t)}{(t-2)(t+2)}$$

Comment: Replace $t-2$ with $x$ and obtain $\lim_{x\to 0} (...)$

Comment: By L'Hospital, $\cos(t-2)/2t\to1/4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not directly using $\;\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}\frac{\sin(x-x_0)}{x-x_0}=1\;$ ?:

$$\frac{\sin(t-2)}{t^2-4}=\frac1{t+2}\cdot\frac{\sin(t-2)}{t-2}\xrightarrow[t\to2]{}\ldots$$

Comment: Hmm, where is that definition or theorem from? I am familiar with sin(x) / x = 1 when the limit approaches 0. Can you provide a link so the question becomes more understandable for novices?

Comment: What..? I am asking about the formula you laid out after the words "Why not directly using". Where is that from?

Comment: @FateMetric You can reach that by means of basic substitution: $$t:=x-x_0\;,\;\;\text{so}\;\;x\to x_0\iff t\to 0\,\,\,\text{ , and then}$$$$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{\sin(x-x_0)}{x-x_0}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin t}t=1$$

Comment: Hmm, you can change the approximation like that, from x -> x0 to t -> 0? Interesting, well, anyway, your answers is what I deem most clear and understandable :)

Comment: @FateMetric You can do that kind of substitutions **always**... *as long* as your function remains well defined around the new points, of course.

Comment: So, I need to think about the denominator and numerator if they are suitable for the point for which we wish to be zero?

Comment: @FateMetric Well, yes *in this case*, as the function is a trigonometric rational one. Everything is well defined everywhere except at the point towards the variable tends, so you can do it.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{ t \to 2 }\frac { \sin(t-2) }{ t^{ 2 }-4 } =\lim_{ t\to 2 }\frac { \sin(t-2) }{ \left( t-2 \right)  } \frac { 1 }{ \left( t+2 \right)  } =\frac { 1 }{ 4 } $$

Comment: What $x$ has to do with $t-2$?!

Comment: @polfosol Come on: that's an obvious typo.

Answer (score 1):

No, no need to take derivatives or using L'Hospital.

But it's clear that you *can* do so:  $$\lim_{t\to2} \frac{\sin(t-2)}{t^2-4}\quad\overbrace{=}^{L'Hospital}\quad \lim_{t\to 2} \frac{\big(\sin(t-2)\big)'}{(t^2-4)'} = \quad \lim_{t \to 2} \frac{\cos(t-2)}{2t} =\frac 14$$

Comment: How did you get the cosine and the 2t?

Comment: I used L'hopital's rule and took limit of the fraction given by (derivative of numerator)/(derivative of denominator)

Comment: I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Oh! I understand, thank you!

Comment: Of course, you can also trust other answerer's claim that $\lim_{t\to 2}\frac {\sin(f(t))}{f(t)} =1$, but you should take the time to search for an explanation, rather than merely trusting it's true.